# Show that there are radios $\epsilon_x> 0 $ and $\epsilon_y> 0$ such that: $ B(x,\epsilon_x) \cap B(y,\epsilon_y) = \emptyset $

Tags: general-topology

Let $x, y ∈ R^{n}$ with $x \not= y $ Show that there are radii $\epsilon_x> 0 $ and $\epsilon_y> 0$ such that:

$$ B(x,\epsilon_x) \cap B(y,\epsilon_y) = \emptyset $$

I was thinking of defining $d(x, y) = 1 + \dfrac{1}{min(x, y)}$ but when looking for the intersection and defining the $\epsilon$ I can't move on

Comment: $\min(x,y)$ means nothing.

Comment: What do you mean "radios"?  ratios?  rationals? radii?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :** Defining
$$\epsilon_x=\epsilon_y = \frac{d(x,y)}{3}$$
(where $d$ is the distance for which the balls are defined) should work.

Comment: Following the logic, is it correct to choose the $\epsilon_x = \epsilon_y = \frac{d(x, y)}{\alpha}$    with $\alpha \in ] 2, +\infty [$?

Comment: Yes, it is correct !

Answer (score 0):

Take $d(x,y)$ which is distance between x and y and usually in R^n it is given by $(\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_i-y_i|^2)^{1/2}$ so if we choose $\epsilon_x=d(x,y)/4 \enspace$ similarly $\epsilon_y=d(x,y)/4$ we're done.

Comment: If the balls are defined with respect to another metric, this has no reason to work.

Comment: this would work for any metric

Comment: I mean that the question of the OP is talking about balls, so implicitely there is already a metric. If you define your $\epsilon$'s w.r.t. **another** metric (as you did, chosing the metric from the euclidian norm), it has no reason to work.

Comment: ok if you say so i just couldn't come up with counter example ( and i already got the another part :/ ) Edit: Assuming that some element z belongs to both "Balls" derives contradiction

Comment: Imagine for example that the original metric chosen by the OP is $$d_0(x,y)=\frac{ (\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_i-y_i|^2)^{1/2}}{10}$$ Then letting 
$$\epsilon_x=\epsilon_y = \frac{ (\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_i-y_i|^2)^{1/2}}{4}$$
will not work.

Comment: i think you are misunderstanding my answer i should put usually before the "and in $R^n$" part

Comment: I think *you* are misunderstanding my comments ;) If the OP considers the balls for the metric $d_0$ I defined previously (which is possible, since the OP did not say which metric was used for the question), then your definition of $\epsilon_x$ and $\epsilon_y$ doesn't work. For example in that case, both $x$ and $y$ belong to the intersection.

Comment: if we choose another metric $d_0$ then $\epsilon_x$ becomes $d_0/4$ what i meant was this. And you say this is still wrong ok then but im not convinced :/

Comment: What you meant was this, but what you wrote is not this. And what you wrote is not correct.

Comment: No actually it is correct i wrote take the distance i did not say distance is this or that i wrote take the distance d(x,y)  and then i said it is "usually" this. I'm new so i couldn't start a chat with you and this long discussion happened. this may or may not help the op :D

Comment: OP already has a distance, he does not have to take one. I am sure you understood the point, but your answer is too unclear, in my opinion.

Comment: as you wrote OP's distance has no meaning.And what is the difference between your answer and mine im actually very curious i hope some admin or editor sees this! 13.000 reputation and what you are doing is unbelievable to a newcomer